# jquery-using val() function

Tags: jquery

```
<form id="form" action=" ">
<div class="error"><ul></ul></div>
<input type="text" id="name_2" />

<input type="text" id="age_2" />
<input type="submit" value="Click here!" />
<script>
$('#form').on('click',function($event){
    $event.preventDefault();
    var form=$(this);
    var name=form.find('#name_2').val();
    var email=form.find('#age_2').val();
    var find=form.find('p.msg');
    if(name==''&&email==''){

        $('<p></p>',{
                text:"all fields must be filled",
                class:'msg'

                }).insertBefore('#form');


    }
    else{

        console.log(name + email);
    }

});
```

hi,
the problem with the above code is that when i focus on the input,the text,all fields must be filled is added and also when i focus on the other input instead of checking when i click on the Click me button.how can i modify the code to check only when the submit is clicked and insert the text(all fields are required) only once

Comment: `on('click',` should be `on('submit',`

Comment: You should look into using a validation plugin like [jquery validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Answer (score 1):

use submit handler instead of `click()`.. and `return false` if the condition is true

```
 $('#form').on('submit',function($event){
$event.preventDefault();
var form=$(this);
var name=form.find('#name_2').val();
var email=form.find('#age_2').val();
var find=form.find('p.msg');
if(name==''&& email==''){

    $('<p></p>',{
            text:"all fields must be filled",
            class:'msg'

            }).insertBefore('#form');
     return false

}
else{

    console.log(name + email);
}

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the form submit event to validate the form and if it is not valid return `false` to cancel the form submit

Also you may have to change the condition from `name==''&&email==''` to `name=='' || email==''` to validate both fields are not blank

```
$('#form').on('submit',function($event){
    $event.preventDefault();
    var form=$(this);
    var name=form.find('#name_2').val();
    var email=form.find('#age_2').val();
    var find=form.find('p.msg');
    if(name=='' || email==''){

        $('<p></p>',{
            text:"all fields must be filled",
            class:'msg'

        }).insertBefore('#form');

        return false
    }
    else{

        console.log(name + email);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

**in html**

```
<form id="form" action=" ">
<div class="error"><ul></ul></div>
<input type="text" id="name_2" />

<input type="text" id="age_2" />
<input type="submit" value="Click here!" id="submitbtn" />
```

**In JS**

```
$('#submitbtn').on('click',function($event){
    $event.preventDefault();
    var form=$(this);
    var name=form.find('#name_2').val();
    var email=form.find('#age_2').val();
    var find=form.find('p.msg');
    if(name==''&&email==''){

        $('<p></p>',{
                text:"all fields must be filled",
                class:'msg'

                }).insertBefore('#form');


    }
    else{

        console.log(name + email);
    }

})
```

;